# How can i make static header for a web page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I am trying to make a header for a website and i do not want header(which contain logo, search bar and nav's) to be scrolled up it should be static at one place as we have here for https://stackoverflow.com/ website.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_fixed_menu.asp

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for creating a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best to provide code for future reference but use a CSS selector to select the element you want to stick at the top of the page. Using `position: fixed` with property `top:0` essentially takes it out of the flow of the DOM.

Lets say:

**html**

```
<div class="navbar">
 <ul>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.navbar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Bootstrap is used and tested CSS framework that helps reduce development time, and has documentation for numerous scenarios, one being fixed nav. Check it out https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-top-fixed/

Answer (score 0):

Just add:

```
position: fixed;
```

to your header class

Comment: what if i want the header to slide up for certain height and get fixed at one point

Answer (score 0):

`position: fixed` is probably what you are looking for. Just add that in CSS to your navbar and you should be golden.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tnocau8h/)

Comment: what if i want the header to slide up for certain height and get fixed at one point

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/position?v=example#Sticky_positioning